# Adding gallery images to category list

Tags: magento2, category-listing

Magento CE 2.2.4

I want to add product gallery images alongside the main image on the category list & use the default gallery UI component if possible.

I can add the gallery images to list.phtml like so:

```
<?php $images = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>
<ul class="list-gallery-images">

<?php foreach($images as $child) : ?>
<li><img class="list-gallery-thumb" src="<?php echo $child->getUrl(); ?>" width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $_product->getSku() ?>" /></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

This outputs the gallery images OK as a simple list, but I'm also looking to include the standard gallery functionality too - so that the **fotorama gallery** is rendered.

Is it possible to just add the following to catalog_category_view.xml?

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Gallery" name="catalog_product_gallery" template="Magento_Catalog::product/gallery.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

If so, how would I reference the the correct $block in **list.phtml**?

Comment: Did u find a solution for this?

Comment: No - I added the images as outlined above & then did some jquery to swap out the main image as required.